# too many values error message in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select some records using two tables `avion` and `vol`, but when I run my statement I get this error :

> ORA-00913: too many values

This is my statement :

```
select distinct avion.avnum, avion.avnom from avion, vol
where avion.avnum  = vol.avnum 
AND vol.plnum in (
  select pilote.plnum, pilote.salaire from pilote
  where salaire > (
    select salaire from pilote
    where plnom ='Tsukishima'
  )
)
AND avion.avnom <> 'Boeing 777';
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct avion.avnum, avion.avnom from avion, vol
where avion.avnum  = vol.avnum 
AND vol.plnum in (
  select pilote.plnum from pilote
  where salaire > (
    select salaire from pilote
    where plnom ='Tsukishima'
  )
)
AND avion.avnom <> 'Boeing 777';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, can you please explain why it didn't worked in the first statement

Comment: Because in your first statement, you were including 2 values in the IN clause (pilote.plnum and pilote.salaire). the IN clause expect only 1 value (the one that match vol.plnum)